# Apply External CSS gives no Styles

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Hello there I am new to ASP.NET and learning to my own! The problem is that I want to add External CSS Styles to my web page. For this I have created an external CSS and dragged it on my page to import it to my web page! like:

```
   <link href="file:///D:\C#%20Work%20Space\Login%20Demo\mystyler.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
```

Then, I added a class into my CSS as:

```
   .container
   {
   background:red;
   margin-top:100px;
   margin-left:100px;
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   }
```

and I am using in for a simple div element as:

```
   <!html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <!head runat="server">
   <!title>Untitled Page</title>
   <!link href="file:///D:\C#%20Work%20Space\Login%20Demo\mystyler.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
   </head>
   <!body>
   <!form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div class="container"> Here I want to add External CSS Class
    <!h1>Hello</h1>
   </div>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

So, The problem is my External CSS is not giving any styles to my web page! Is it me doing something wrong Please can somebody help me!
Thanks in advance

Comment: that doesn't look like a good file path to me. Try dragging the css file from your solution explorer onto your header section.

Comment: I have done it in the same way

Comment: it might look something like: **~/Content/Styles/mystyler.css** if you've placed your css sheet in your content -> styles folder

Comment: The thing is it shows the styles in my VS Design View but not in the Web Browser!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
   <link href="file:///D:\C#%20Work%20Space\Login%20Demo\mystyler.css" rel="stylesheet"
type="text/css" />
```

to

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyler.css" />
```

Where `Login%20Demo` is the root of your app

Comment: if `Login%20Demo` it shall work then change it to `loginDemo` avoid space in folderName while creating the folder. You may want to try `href="/mystyler.css"` too or `href="../mystyler.css"`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you use '!'symbol inside the link tag. Remove it and check whether your external css styles works or not.